# "use" statements in php file

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, traits

I am a beginner in Laravel and while learning about "namespace" and "use" statements, I found that, for example, in Controllers, when we first write "use" statements it should be repeated inside of the function.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{

    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Why is this working so? Why is not it enough to write "use" statements once without repeating in a function? And also, if I will create another Controller with the same namespace, should I write the same "use" statements there as well?

Comment: install phpstorm if you dont yet, storm make learning easy and fast

Comment: @TsV I wouldn't say it's better for learning - just better for productivity, it doesn't explain what it's doing - it just does it. It's best to learn PHP then utilise tools like PHPStorm

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Ctrl + LMB  explain a lot

Comment: @TsV it can do - but not always, some times code navigation isn't a complete trail

Comment: It's not Laravel related, it's basically PHP. "First" `use` is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). "Second" `use` is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two different `use` in PHP:

1. To [*alias*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) namespaced names,
2. to apply [*traits*](http://php.net/trait) to classes.

The `use` at the top of the file aliases namespaced names into shorter local ones. Literally their only use is so you can write `DispatchesJobs` inside this one file instead of having to always use the fully qualified name `\Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs`.

`use` inside a `class` applies that *trait* to the class.

In this case you could omit the first `use` to alias the trait, and apply it using its fully qualified name:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Controller extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller {
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    ...
}
```

This does exactly the same thing, but is obviously rather verbose. Establishing a few aliases at the top of the file allows your following code to be terser.

Answer (score 1):

Using keyword `use` outside class is just importing specific part called `trait`.

And using keyword `use` inside class is actually inheriting or implements to use that `trait`

Comment: Thank you! So, if I will create a new Controller with the same namespace (namespace App\Http\Controllers;),  this "trait" will be imported in this file as well, right?

Comment: @BSCH, namespace = virtual folder, like you can have Job\Music\Mp3.php and Home\Music\Mp3.php, same name - different folders - different files, trait - code that you inject directy in another code.